# Review on my multiple JQuery Slider on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have successfully placed multiple jquery ui slider on a page and its transalation text too. you can check it live on:
http://outsourcingnepal.com/projects/jQuery%20slider/

I have my jquery code as :

```
var arrLabel1 = new Array('Not Good', 'OK', 'Average', 'Above Average', 'Excellent', 'Outstanding');
$(function() {
    $( ".slider_control" ).slider({
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#slider_" + $(this).attr('rel') ).val( ui.value );
            $( "#label_" + $(this).attr('rel') ).text( arrLabel1[ ui.value ] );
        }
    }).each(function(index){
        $( "#slider_" + (index + 1) ).val( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
        $( "#label_" + (index + 1) ).text( arrLabel1[ $(this).slider( "value" ) ] );
    });
});
```

Now i would like to optimize it so that i can be independent of rel attribute.

MY HTML:

```
<ul class="slider-container"> 
    <li class="ui_slider"> 
        <div class="title">Overall: <span id="label_1"></span></div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="overall_review" id="slider_1" /> 
        <div class="slider_control" rel="1"></div> 
    </li> 
    <li class="ui_slider"> 
        <div class="title">Cleanliness: <span id="label_2"></span></div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="overall_review" id="slider_2" /> 
        <div class="slider_control" rel="2"></div> 
    </li> 
    <li class="ui_slider"> 
        <div class="title">Facilities: <span id="label_3"></span></div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="overall_review" id="slider_3" /> 
        <div class="slider_control" rel="3"></div> 
    </li> 
    <li class="ui_slider"> 
        <div class="title">Location: <span id="label_4"></span></div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="overall_review" id="slider_4" /> 
        <div class="slider_control" rel="4"></div> 
    </li> 
    <li class="ui_slider"> 
        <div class="title">Quality of Service: <span id="label_5"></span></div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="overall_review" id="slider_5" /> 
        <div class="slider_control" rel="5"></div> 
    </li> 
    <li class="ui_slider"> 
        <div class="title">Room: <span id="label_6"></span></div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="overall_review" id="slider_6" /> 
        <div class="slider_control" rel="6"></div> 
    </li> 
    <li class="ui_slider"> 
        <div class="title">Value of Money: <span id="label_7"></span></div> 
        <input type="hidden" name="overall_review" id="slider_7" /> 
        <div class="slider_control" rel="7"></div> 
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my option your code has two problems:

1. You unnecessarily fill your HTML with empty elements which you could just create in your script. Changing that would remove the necessity for the `rel` attribute.
2. more importantly (even if there are people that may disagree), you have unnecessarily made your form dependent on JavaScript. It would be much better to have `select` elements in your HTML, which you can replace with sliders. That way even users without JavaScript can use your form unrestricted.

I've written an example how I would do it:

```
$(".ui_slider select").each(function() {
    var select = $(this); // Cache a refernce to the current select
    var sliderDiv = $("<div></div>"); // create a div for the slider
    var displayLabel = $("<span></span>"); // create a span to display current selection

    if (select[0].selectedIndex < 0) // Make sure that an item is selected
        select[0].selectedIndex = 0;

    select
        .hide() // hide the select
        .before( // Insert display label before the select
            displayLabel
               .text(select.find("option:selected").text()) // and set it's default text
        )
        .after( 
           sliderDiv // Insert the silder div after the select
               .data("select", select) // store a reference to the select
               .data("label", displayLabel) // store a reference to the display label
               .slider({
                    max: select.find("option").length - 1, // set to number of items in select
                    slide: function(event, ui) {
                        var select = $(this).data("select"); 
                        select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value; // update the select
                        $(this).data("label").text( // Update the display label
                            select.find("option:selected").text()
                        );
                    }
               })
        );
});
```

HTML (repeat as needed):

```
<div class="ui_slider">
    <label for="overall">Overall: </label>
    <select name="overall" id="overall">
        <option value="0">Not Good</option>
        <option value="1">OK</option>
        <option value="2">Average</option>
        <option value="3">Above Average</option>
        <option value="4">Excellent</option>
        <option value="5">Outstanding</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/YfqCx/2/

Comment: your suggestions are really good ones...